# Mountain Lion Menu Bar CGBlendMode

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, cgcontext

What's the `CGBlendMode` of the Menu Bar is on Mountain Lion? My first guess is `kCGBlendModeOverlay`, but that seems a bit too transparent.

Any ideas? I'm trying to make a NSView with a gradient match the look of the Menu Bar.

Answer (score 0):

CGBlendMode in default non customized menu bar is kCGBlendModeNormal.

Trick is in CGColorSetFillColorWithColor. CGColorSetFillColorWithColor is the basic function call underneath when you are trying to set any fill activity like any Color, Gradient or Pattern.

In Mountain Lion, I think its just simple gray color with low alpha.